# Is it worth to study the "Membrane Paradigm" of black holes nowadays?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, magnetohydrodynamics

I'm very interested in the region near the outer event horizon and its magnetohydrodynamic enviroment physics. For instance, I'm beggining to study the Blandford-Znajek process, and subjects related. But, something very interesting is starting to appear in the texts: the membrane paradigm. This model consider that the outer event horizon $r_{+}$ of the spinning black hole can be viewed as a sort of stretching perfect conducting "membrane". To be honest, there are a lot of theoretical results that convienced me that this is a nice and well-stablished model to invest some time of study.

But, a event horizon isn't a membrane and therefore there is nothing to sustain a "perfect conducting" region. Also, although the Blandford-Znajek paper predicts electromagnetic energy extraction from the hole, their study didn't mention a "membrane"; in other words, it seems that this theoretical setup wasn't necessary to predict new phenomena. These kind of fundamental problems annoys me. Also, I've read a thesis that argues:

> Along the horizon, between $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$, the plasma may again cross the
> field lines, since the membrane paradigm prevents us from viewing it as entering the hole.
>
> [image]

Well, a time-like particle cannot hover the $r_{+}$, so I don't see how can exist a flux of matter between $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$.

**So, my question is:**

**From a Astrophysical/Magnetohydrodynamic point of view, in the case we are dealling with a region very close to the hole, is it worth to invest time to study the whole theory and implications of the "Membrane Paradigm"?**

Comment: Two votes to close this question but I have no idea why...

Comment: @MitchellPorter This question showed some merit: two upvotes, so why close it? Furthermore, I wrote it because I think I read somewhere saying that this model for the astrophysics near the event horozion was outdated, but I need some kind of confirmation.

Comment: @MitchellPorter The close votes are probably because of the phrasing.  Whether or not it's "worth it to invest time" in something is a value judgement, not something that has an definitive answer.  If the question was something like "does the membrane paradigm lead to an inconsistency with the flux of matter between $P$ and $Q$?" then I don't think there would be any close votes.